# Powershell Specific Json Value

Tags: arrays, json, powershell

I have a json that I wanted to generate using Powershell

```
{

"CreatedBy": "div",

"Label": "jss key",

"Scopes": ["content-#everything#", "audience-delivery"]

}
```

I am using the below to generate the json but it is not successful

```
$EdgeClientID = 'fsfsdfSDFsda'

$scope = '[ "content-#everything#", "audience-delivery" ]'

$body = @{

    'CreatedBy'     = $EdgeClientID

    'Label' = 'jss key'

    'Scopes'    = $scope

} | ConvertTo-Json
```

the result I am getting is

```
{

    "CreatedBy":  "fsfsdfSDFsda",

    "Label":  "jss key",

    "Scopes":  "[\"content-#everything#\", \"audience-delivery\"]"

}
```

The value of **scope** is not coming right. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 2):

The reason why you're not getting the desired output from it is because the following is an *array* only in the context of JSON and not in the context of PowerShell and `ConvertTo-Json` interprets it a simple *string*:

```
$scope = '[ "content-#everything#", "audience-delivery" ]'
```

The following should fix the problem:

```
$EdgeClientID = 'fsfsdfSDFsda'
$scope = "content-#everything#", "audience-delivery"
$body = @{
    'CreatedBy' = $EdgeClientID
    'Label'     = 'jss key'
    'Scopes'    = $scope
} | ConvertTo-Json
```

You could also create a blue print class for your JSON:

```
class JSONBluePrint {
    [string]$CreatedBy
    [string]$Label
    [object[]]$Scopes

    JSONBluePrint () { }
    JSONBluePrint([string]$CreatedBy, [string]$Label, [object[]]$Scopes)
    {
        $this.CreatedBy = $CreatedBy
        $this.Label = $Label
        $this.Scopes = $Scopes
    }

    [string] ToJson () {
        return $this | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100
    }
}

[JSONBluePrint]::new(
    'div',
    'jss key',
    @('content-#everything#', 'audience-delivery')
).ToJson()

$json = [JSONBluePrint]::new()
$json.CreatedBy = 'div'
$json.Label = 'jss key'
$json.Scopes = 'content-#everything#', 'audience-delivery'
$json.ToJson()
```